# How can Turing machine compare to a computer?

Tags: turing-machines, computer-science-theory, abstract-machine

I have read articles including [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) about Turing machine. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236000/whats-a-turing-machine) is also question about Turing machine.  After reading those, what I understand about T.M is it's just a logical machine with infinite tape, R/W head and a table with rules. If it's true, without that table a Turing machine is nothing. even a simple computer can do everything from simple word processing to playing games, but how can a Turing machine compare to a computer.

Comment: It seems like what you’re looking for is [Turing Completeness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37247136)

Comment: "A simple computer can do everything from simple word processing to playing games": the word processor is a set of rules, so is the game, so is the operating system, so is the CPU's instruction set. A computer without those is like a Turing machine without rules or anything on its input tape. A computer follows instructions much like a Turing machine does. Modern computers are more similar to RASP machines (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine) than Turing machines, but the two are equivalent (as that article explains).

Comment: @Welbog So, the main part of the Turing machine is a set of rules. If one define a program with a set of rule and it can satisfy all of the proper input then will that program be a Turing machine?

Comment: Turing machines are really no different from any programming language: they encode computations and can be acted upon by machinery to perform the computations they encode. For x86 assembly language, it's CPUs. For Turing machines, it's typically people, but you can write interpreters for Turing machines much the same as people have written interpreters for Python. Turing machines don't "do" anything more than a program written in C++.

Comment: This question belongs on http://cs.stackexchange.com .